# Connection Refused When Trying To Connect To IRCd-Hybrid

Tags: connection, rackspace, irc, rackspace-cloud

I have a Rackspace server running Ubuntu Lucid Lynx, where I have installed an `IRCd-Hybrid`. I can connect to the IRC server using `irssi` that was installed on the same machine where the server is, but when I try to access it from my computer at home or my friends try I get this error:

> Connection Refused

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that probably means a firewall somewhere is blocking the connection.  On your home machine, try connecting directly to the IRC port on your server.  If you are running linux you can do this with telnet:

```
$ telnet your.example.server 6667
```

you should get some response from the server (you might have to hit `enter` first).

If that doesn't work, there's probably a firewall involved.  Check the server where you are running ircd.  What does the output of `/sbin/iptables -nvL` show for firewall rules?  I bet you have a standard 'default-deny' setup, where incoming connections are dropped unless they are going to specific predefined ports.

Comment: I got this: `telnet: connect to address 50.56.93.249: Connection refused\n
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host`

Comment: That actually sounds like there isn't a service listening on the remote port.  Check your ircd config file and see what interfaces it is configured to listen to, and what ports.  You might only be set up to listen on localhost, which is why it works on the server but nowhere else.

Answer (score -1):

I think I moved my ircd.conf file on accident when trying to touch the MOTD file..
Restored the ircd.conf file, restarted the ircd-hybrid service, and we're good!